# Laravel Installation:Pacakge is not found even if php version is greater than 5

Tags: php, laravel

I  have installed laravel framework via git using this `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist` command.But i will get the following error

```
Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.4 requires php >=5.4.0 -> no matching package found
Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your min
imum-stability setting
```

My php version is 5.6.3 i have referred some questions related to my problem but didn't help me.

CMPOSER.JSON

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `composer.json`  code?

Comment: Maybe you have multiple PHP versions installed and it's not recognizing the newer version. What does `php -v` in the command line yield?

Comment: php -v returns version 5.3.28

Comment: @set kyar i have updated my question

Comment: Can you check your php version with `<?php phpinfo() ?>` ? Not from command line, I means

Comment: Yes that version is 5.6.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the command line is using an old PHP version (5.3.28).

#### Unix

In a LAMP environment run `whereis php` to see where the PHP binary is located and delete it.

#### Windows

In windows it's a bit trickier. You can search for the PHP installation(s) manually or try to figure it out using the PATH variable (type `PATH` in the console)

---

Then try to run `php -v` again. Hopefully it should now use the newer version.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter but best would be from your project path

Comment: I wii get the command not found error both project path and outside path

Comment: Are you running windows?

Comment: Oh sorry, I was assuming a LAMP setup... Can you locate your PHP installation(s) ? You could look in the PATH variable (type `PATH` in the console)

Comment: Great! I've added the instructions for windows to my question so it might help others too :)